# How to Edit Track in Google "My Tracks"?

Tags: google-maps

I frequently for get to turn off Google My Tracks recording. When forget this after biking or hiking, it leaves a big trail on my track from where I got into my car and drove home. Is there an easy way to trim this portion of the track? Or to enter an edit mode in My Tracks or Google Maps to remove the extra section?

Thanks!

(PS can some one add a tag for google-my-tracks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Upload the map to Google from your device
- On maps.google.com, click "My maps" (top left, below the Google Maps logo)
- Select the map you want to edit
- Click the 'edit' button (top right in the left sidebar)
- The line is now editable. Right-click points on the line you want to delete and select 'Delete this point'.

Comment: Is there a way to send it back to My Tracks?

Comment: endolith, at the moment you cannot do that. See http://groups.google.com/group/mytracks/browse_thread/thread/0aec47f8dec64588#.